# Is it ok to mention about your stack profile in resume?

Tags: resume, career-development, career-switch

I am related to IT domain(Web development) so is it ok to mention stack activity in resume?

Currently I am mentioning it in my resume under skills and hobbies section like this -

> •Technical blog writing and Q/A at technical web forums during my
>   spare time specially on stackoverflow sites and codecademy.

What are the pros and cons of using it? Is it sounds professional or I should remove it ?

I am looking for a job now, so concerned about these things.

My resume [link](http://www.docdroid.net/2tv0/resume.doc.html)

Comment: Let's look at it this way: your prospective employer may learn a few things about you, and these won't necessarily be positive. For one thing, your Q/A ratio, and that your reputation on SO is 0.9 milliSkeets.

Comment: @DeerHunter milliSkeets... lol.. I bet no body who is not on SO got this :) .. what if he got Mr.Skeet to endorse his linkedin profile ?

Answer (score 2):

Your Stack Overflow profile gives potential employers a chance to look at you actually coding, as well as your ability to solve problems and seek help. If you have any amount of reputation there say put it under hobbies as you have already with either a URL alongside your contact info so they can look at your profile directly or a bullet point under "Misc"/"Other" with your rep.